# Dialog stack workflow Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog workflow where the first dialog (D1) opens a second one (D2). I want D2 to be able to go back D1 (closing itself and openning D1).
Following Material Angular documentation, creating the references needed for each dialog creates a circular dependecy as Dialog 1 reference Dialog 2 and Dialog 2 references Dialog 1. D1->D2->D1.

Anyway I can pass a reference for D1 to D2 or other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really hard to know if you don't include any code, but what I would do is control the dialogs from the component which opens the first one

Comment: That's exactly what I did eventually, using EventEmitters to notify actions to parent. Thank you!